# Does SendGrid scan files that are attached?

Tags: sendgrid

I'm looking for info on whether SendGrid scans files that are attached as emails.  If we provide a service for our users to send an email through SendGrid, we want to prevent them from sending something malicious.

Looking at their list of Attachment Error codes, it doesn't look like there is anything like "can't send message with attachment because it failed a virus scan"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

The [full feature breakdown on the pricing page](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/) does not mention scanning for malicious attachments, and as you've discovered neither do the error codes, so I don't believe SendGrid does automatic scanning of attachments.

I imagine it would be difficult to  get this right for users. Defining malicious depends on your threat model. I know I can't use my Twilio email address to receive JavaScript files, for example, but that might not be right for your users.

I would recommend that you investigate scanning files yourself after they are uploaded, before you allow users to send them through your application.